Conflict between protobuf-javalite (Firebase) and protobuf-java (google-cloud-datastore) in a Flutter/Android project with an external Java module
I am working on a Flutter/Android project that integrates an external Java module called dtp. The project encounters a dependency conflict between two versions of Protobuf: protobuf-javalite and protobuf-java.
Here’s the situation:
Flutter/Android: To interact with Firebase, I need protobuf-javalite, which is required by Firebase libraries such as firebase-auth, firebase-firestore, etc.
The Java module (dtp): This module uses protobuf-java because it needs to interact with the com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore library, which requires this version of Protobuf.
Problem:
The two versions of Protobuf (protobuf-javalite and protobuf-java) are causing class conflicts and errors during compilation, as they use similar classes and APIs. This leads to class duplication and code generation issues.
/root-project
│
├── android/ 
│   ├── app/ (Application Android Flutter)
│   │   ├── build.gradle 
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   └── main/
│   │   │       ├── java/ 
│   │   │       │   ├── com/
│   │   │       │   │   └── mycompany/
│   │   │       │   │       └── mycode/ 
│   │   │       ├── res/ (Ressources Android)
│   │   │       ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│   │   │       └── ... 
│   │   ├── dtp/ (Module Java )
│   │   │   ├── build.gradle
│   │   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   │   └── main/
│   │   │   │       ├── java/ 
│   │   │   │       └── ... 
│   │   └── ... (
│
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle

I’ve tried using the com.google.protobuf plugin in Gradle to force a specific version, but this didn’t solve the conflict, as Firebase specifically requires protobuf-javalite and google-cloud-datastore requires protobuf-java.
I have explored exclusion options in Gradle to exclude one of the versions of Protobuf, but this breaks certain Firebase or google-cloud-datastore functionalities.
I've also tried to integrate my java code (dtp) as a jar file but i have the same duplicate class or missing class; Specially this class :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3;
Here are the depedencies of my Android/app/build.gradle :

implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.13.1'
implementation ('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0')
implementation ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.40.0')
implementation ('org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.0.202109080827-r')
implementation ("org.datatransferproject:portability-spi-transfer:1.0.4")
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.31.1'
implementation (project(":dtp")) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'protolite-well-known-types'
}


And my Android/dtp/build.gradle :
   implementation platform ('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.26.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module:'protobuf-java'
    }
    implementation ("org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:6.10.0.202406032230-r")
    implementation ("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
    }

    implementation ('org.datatransferproject:portability-data-transfer-google:1.0.4'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
//        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',  module: 'protobuf-java'
    }

    implementation("org.datatransferproject:portability-types-common:1.0.4"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',  module: 'protobuf-java'
    }
    implementation ("org.datatransferproject:portability-spi-transfer:1.0.4"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',  module: 'protobuf-java'
    }
    implementation ("org.datatransferproject:portability-api-launcher:1.0.4"){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',  module: 'protobuf-java'
    }
    implementation('org.datatransferproject:portability-types-transfer:1.0.4'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf',  module: 'protobuf-java'
    }
    implementation ('org.datatransferproject:portability-cloud-google:1.0.4'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
//        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-javalite'
 //       exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    }

    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.31.1'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.40.1'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.0'

    implementation ('io.grpc:grpc-alts:1.18.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    }

